# Evaluating $\frac1{n^2+1^2}+\frac2{n^2+2^2}+\dots+\frac n{n^2+n^2}$ using Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

[image: Riemann sum to evaluate limits question]

Not sure how to get started on this question. Do I have to form the summation? If yes, how do I go about doing it? Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For a) we have
\begin{align}
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{k}{n^2+k^2}=  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{k/n}{n(1+k^2/n^2)} = \int^1_0 \frac{x}{1+x^2}\ dx.
\end{align}
Likewise, we can expression b) as an integral
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 \sin \pi x\ dx.
\end{align}